# Multiple primary keys in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, unique-constraint

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE word(
word CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL,
id BIGINT NOT NULL,
repeat INTEGER NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE public.word OWNER TO postgres;
ALTER TABLE ONLY  word ADD CONSTRAINT "ID_PKEY" PRIMARY KEY (word,id);
```

When I try to restore it using following command:

```
psql -U postgres -h localhost -d word -f word.sql
```

it gives me this error:

> multiple primary keys for table "word" are not allowed

How can I use multiple primary keys in postgres?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

> how can i use multiple primary keys in postgres ?

You can't. It's an oxymoron - the definition of a primary key is that it's *the* primary key, singular. You can't have more than one.

You can have multiple `unique` constraints. You can have a primary key that contains multiple columns (a composite primary key). But you can't have more than one primary key for a table.

However, the code you show doesn't produce the error you mentioned:

```
$ psql -U postgres regress <<__END__
CREATE TABLE word(
word CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL,
id BIGINT NOT NULL,
repeat INTEGER NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE public.word OWNER TO postgres;
ALTER TABLE ONLY  word ADD CONSTRAINT "ID_PKEY" PRIMARY KEY (word,id);
__END__
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
$
```

At a guess you've actually already defined this table and you're ignoring the previous errors, then showing only the last one. If I re-run this code I get the output:

```
ERROR:  relation "word" already exists
ALTER TABLE
ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "word" are not allowed
```

The real error here is the first one, of course.

I strongly recommend always using `-v ON_ERROR_STOP=1` in `psql`, e.g.:

```
$ psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -U postgres regress <<__END__
CREATE TABLE word(
word CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL,
id BIGINT NOT NULL,
repeat INTEGER NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE public.word OWNER TO postgres;
ALTER TABLE ONLY  word ADD CONSTRAINT "ID_PKEY" PRIMARY KEY (word,id);
__END__

ERROR:  relation "word" already exists
$
```

See how it stops at the first error?

(It'd be the default but that'd break backward compatibility).

Answer (score 9):

You can define a table like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    field1 INTEGER,
    field2 INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (field1, field2)
);
```